# Why is react i18next not working ? no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

The translations do not work I only see the keys. Instead of having "Welcome to MySite" I only have "welcome.title MySite".

my **i18nextConf.js** file

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

const fallbackLng = ['fr'];
const availableLanguages = ['en','fr'];

i18n
    .use(Backend) // load translations using http (default public/assets/locals/en/translations)
    .use(LanguageDetector) // detect user language
    .use(initReactI18next) // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
    .init({
        fallbackLng, // fallback language is english.
        backend: {
            /* translation file path */
            // loadPath: './translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
            loadPath: './translations/{{lng}}/common.json'
        },

        detection: {
            checkWhitelist: true, // options for language detection
        },

        debug: false,

        whitelist: availableLanguages,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false, // no need for react. it escapes by default
        },
    });

export default i18n;
```

My **index.js** file

```
import React,{ Suspense } from 'react';
import './i18nextConf';

// code omitted

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <App />
            </Suspense>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My translations files in **src/translations/en/common.json** and **src/translations/fr/common.json**

```
{
    "welcome": {
        "title": "Welcome to "
    }
}
```

my **CustomComponent.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";
class CustomComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const { t } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="section-title">
                <h2 className={classes.myTitle}>{t('welcome.title')}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(CustomComponent);
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration ? What do I have to change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those translation files will be served from the base path from where your `index.html` is also loaded and in-case it's an app created using `create-react-app`, that folder is **public**.

So I think when you are saying in `loadPath` that load files from `./translations/{{lng}}/common.json`, the request actually gets resolved to `public/translation/en/common.json` but your files are located at `src.....` as you stated.

You can try either moving those files inside **public** (check [this](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react) example for reference also ) or you can try the other syntax where you explicitly import the json from each file (inside **src**) and add it to a `resources` object which you pass to configuration as shown [here](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide)

Comment: Moving the files inside public made everything work ! Thanks !